# How to fix Status Code:403 Error in Heroku?

Tags: heroku, backend, netlify

I uploaded my backend to Heroku. However, when I do a fetch POST request from Netlify to the Heroku backend, I got this:

```
   Bad response! Please check your url. Status Code: 403
```

The backend runs but it gives me an error. Thanks..........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Backend.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const flightScanner = require('skiplagged-node-api');
const app = express();
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
let port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
let prices;
let brands;
let resp = [];
let results_Count = 5;
let From = 'SEA';
let To = 'LAX';
let departure_Date = '2022-10-10';

var searchOptions = {
  from: From,
  to: To,
  departureDate: departure_Date,
  resultsCount: results_Count,
  partialTrips: true,
};

async function Flight_Scan() {
  flightScanner(searchOptions)
    .then((response) => {
      // console.log(response);
      resp = [];
      brands = response.map((object) =>
        object.legs.map((object) => object.airline)
      );
      duration = response.map((object) => object.duration);
      price = response.map((object) => object.price);
      timeofFlight = response.map(
        (object) =>
          `${object.departureTime}=>${
            object.legs[object.legs.length - 1].arrivalTime
          }`
      );
      resp.push(
        brands,
        price,
        duration,
        timeofFlight,
        searchOptions.resultsCount
      );
    })
    .catch((err) => (resp = err));
}
app.post('/data', async function (req, res) {
  searchOptions.resultsCount = Number(req.body.Results_Count);
  searchOptions.from = String(req.body.From);
  searchOptions.to = String(req.body.To);
  searchOptions.departureDate = String(req.body.Departure_date);
  await Flight_Scan();
});
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send(resp);
});
app.listen(port, () => console.log('listening on: ' + port));
```

Log Error:

```
>     2022-08-15T05:04:32.880478+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=OPTIONS path="/data" host=final-final-final-app.herokuapp.com
> request_id=92b0787f-3509-4cae-aabc-499e1f69f104 fwd="98.59.250.254"
> dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=204 bytes=301
> protocol=https2022-08-15T05:04:33.017407+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> _events: [Object: null prototype],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017407+00:00 app[web.1]:       _eventsCount: 2,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017408+00:00
> app[web.1]:       _maxListeners:
> undefined,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017408+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> defaultPort: 80,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017408+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> protocol: 'http:',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017408+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> options: [Object: null prototype],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017408+00:00
> app[web.1]:       requests: [Object: null prototype]
> {},2022-08-15T05:04:33.017408+00:00 app[web.1]:       sockets:
> [Object: null prototype],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017409+00:00 app[web.1]: 
> freeSockets: [Object: null prototype]
> {},2022-08-15T05:04:33.017409+00:00 app[web.1]:       keepAliveMsecs:
> 1000,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017409+00:00 app[web.1]:       keepAlive:
> false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017409+00:00 app[web.1]:       maxSockets:
> Infinity,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017409+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> maxFreeSockets: 256,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017409+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> scheduling: 'lifo',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017409+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> maxTotalSockets: Infinity,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017410+00:00 app[web.1]:
> totalSocketCount: 1,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017410+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> [Symbol(kCapture)]: false2022-08-15T05:04:33.017410+00:00 app[web.1]: 
> },2022-08-15T05:04:33.017410+00:00 app[web.1]:     socketPath:
> undefined,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017410+00:00 app[web.1]:     method:
> 'GET',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017410+00:00 app[web.1]:     maxHeaderSize:
> undefined,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017410+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> insecureHTTPParser: undefined,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017411+00:00
> app[web.1]:     path:
> '/api/search.php?from=LAX&to=SEA&depart=2022-08-24&sort=cost',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017411+00:00
> app[web.1]:     _ended: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017411+00:00
> app[web.1]:     res: [Circular *2],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017411+00:00
> app[web.1]:     aborted: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017411+00:00
> app[web.1]:     timeoutCb: null,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017411+00:00
> app[web.1]:     upgradeOrConnect:
> false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017411+00:00 app[web.1]:     parser:
> HTTPParser {2022-08-15T05:04:33.017412+00:00 app[web.1]:       '0':
> null,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017412+00:00 app[web.1]:       '1':
> [Function: parserOnHeaders],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017412+00:00
> app[web.1]:       '2': [Function:
> parserOnHeadersComplete],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017412+00:00 app[web.1]: 
> '3': [Function: parserOnBody],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017412+00:00
> app[web.1]:       '4': [Function:
> parserOnMessageComplete],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017412+00:00 app[web.1]: 
> '5': null,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017413+00:00 app[web.1]:       '6':
> null,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017413+00:00 app[web.1]:       _headers:
> [],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017413+00:00 app[web.1]:       _url:
> '',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017413+00:00 app[web.1]:       socket:
> [Socket],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017413+00:00 app[web.1]:       incoming:
> [Circular *2],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017413+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> outgoing: [Circular *3],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017414+00:00 app[web.1]:  
> maxHeaderPairs: 2000,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017414+00:00 app[web.1]:     
> _consumed: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017414+00:00 app[web.1]:       onIncoming: [Function:
> parserOnIncomingClient],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017414+00:00 app[web.1]:  
> [Symbol(resource_symbol)]:
> [HTTPClientAsyncResource]2022-08-15T05:04:33.017414+00:00 app[web.1]: 
> },2022-08-15T05:04:33.017414+00:00 app[web.1]:     maxHeadersCount:
> null,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017415+00:00 app[web.1]:     reusedSocket:
> false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017415+00:00 app[web.1]:     host:
> 'skiplagged.com',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017415+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> protocol: 'http:',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017415+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017415+00:00 app[web.1]:
> [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017415+00:00
> app[web.1]:     [Symbol(corked)]: 0,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017416+00:00
> app[web.1]:     [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
> host: [Array] }2022-08-15T05:04:33.017416+00:00 app[web.1]:  
> },2022-08-15T05:04:33.017416+00:00 app[web.1]:   [Symbol(kCapture)]:
> false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017416+00:00 app[web.1]:  
> [Symbol(kHeaders)]: null,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017416+00:00 app[web.1]: 
> [Symbol(kHeadersCount)]: 24,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017416+00:00
> app[web.1]:   [Symbol(kTrailers)]:
> null,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017416+00:00 app[web.1]:  
> [Symbol(kTrailersCount)]: 0,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017417+00:00
> app[web.1]:   [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]:
> undefined2022-08-15T05:04:33.017417+00:00 app[web.1]:
> }2022-08-15T05:04:33.017275+00:00 app[web.1]: <ref *2> IncomingMessage
> {2022-08-15T05:04:33.017282+00:00 app[web.1]:   _readableState:
> ReadableState {2022-08-15T05:04:33.017282+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> objectMode: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017283+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> highWaterMark: 16384,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017283+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0
> },2022-08-15T05:04:33.017284+00:00 app[web.1]:     length:
> 0,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017284+00:00 app[web.1]:     pipes:
> [],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017284+00:00 app[web.1]:     flowing:
> null,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017284+00:00 app[web.1]:     ended:
> false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017284+00:00 app[web.1]:     endEmitted:
> false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017285+00:00 app[web.1]:     reading:
> false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017285+00:00 app[web.1]:     constructed:
> true,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017285+00:00 app[web.1]:     sync:
> true,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017285+00:00 app[web.1]:     needReadable:
> false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017286+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> emittedReadable: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017286+00:00 app[web.1]:   
> readableListening: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017286+00:00 app[web.1]: 
> resumeScheduled: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017286+00:00 app[web.1]:   
> errorEmitted: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017286+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> emitClose: true,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017287+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> autoDestroy: true,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017287+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> destroyed: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017287+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> errored: null,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017287+00:00 app[web.1]:     closed:
> false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017287+00:00 app[web.1]:     closeEmitted:
> false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017287+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> defaultEncoding: 'utf8',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017288+00:00 app[web.1]:  
> awaitDrainWriters: null,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017288+00:00 app[web.1]:  
> multiAwaitDrain: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017288+00:00 app[web.1]:   
> readingMore: true,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017288+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> dataEmitted: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017288+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> decoder: null,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017288+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> encoding: null,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017289+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> [Symbol(kPaused)]: null2022-08-15T05:04:33.017289+00:00 app[web.1]:  
> },2022-08-15T05:04:33.017289+00:00 app[web.1]:   _events: [Object:
> null prototype] { end: [Function: responseOnEnd]
> },2022-08-15T05:04:33.017290+00:00 app[web.1]:   _eventsCount:
> 1,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017290+00:00 app[web.1]:   _maxListeners:
> undefined,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017290+00:00 app[web.1]:   socket: <ref
> *1> Socket {2022-08-15T05:04:33.017290+00:00 app[web.1]:     connecting: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017290+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> _hadError: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017290+00:00 app[web.1]:     _parent: null,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017290+00:00 app[web.1]:     _host: 'skiplagged.com',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017290+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> _readableState: ReadableState {2022-08-15T05:04:33.017291+00:00 app[web.1]:       objectMode: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017291+00:00
> app[web.1]:       highWaterMark:
> 16384,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017291+00:00 app[web.1]:       buffer:
> BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0
> },2022-08-15T05:04:33.017291+00:00 app[web.1]:       length:
> 0,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017291+00:00 app[web.1]:       pipes:
> [],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017291+00:00 app[web.1]:       flowing:
> true,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017291+00:00 app[web.1]:       ended:
> false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017292+00:00 app[web.1]:       endEmitted:
> false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017292+00:00 app[web.1]:       reading:
> false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017292+00:00 app[web.1]:       constructed:
> true,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017292+00:00 app[web.1]:       sync:
> false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017292+00:00 app[web.1]:       needReadable:
> true,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017292+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> emittedReadable: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017292+00:00 app[web.1]:   
> readableListening: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017292+00:00 app[web.1]: 
> resumeScheduled: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017293+00:00 app[web.1]:   
> errorEmitted: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017293+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> emitClose: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017293+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> autoDestroy: true,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017293+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> destroyed: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017293+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> errored: null,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017293+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> closed: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017293+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> closeEmitted: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017293+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> defaultEncoding: 'utf8',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017294+00:00 app[web.1]:  
> awaitDrainWriters: null,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017294+00:00 app[web.1]:  
> multiAwaitDrain: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017294+00:00 app[web.1]:   
> readingMore: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017294+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> dataEmitted: true,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017294+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> decoder: null,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017294+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> encoding: null,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017294+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> [Symbol(kPaused)]: false2022-08-15T05:04:33.017294+00:00 app[web.1]:  
> },2022-08-15T05:04:33.017295+00:00 app[web.1]:     _events: [Object:
> null prototype] {2022-08-15T05:04:33.017295+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> end: [Array],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017295+00:00 app[web.1]:       free:
> [Function: onFree],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017295+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> close: [Array],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017295+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> timeout: [Array],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017295+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> agentRemove: [Function: onRemove],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017295+00:00
> app[web.1]:       error: [Function:
> socketErrorListener],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017296+00:00 app[web.1]:     
> data: [Function: socketOnData],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017296+00:00
> app[web.1]:       drain: [Function:
> ondrain]2022-08-15T05:04:33.017296+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> },2022-08-15T05:04:33.017296+00:00 app[web.1]:     _eventsCount:
> 8,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017296+00:00 app[web.1]:     _maxListeners:
> undefined,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017296+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> _writableState: WritableState {2022-08-15T05:04:33.017297+00:00 app[web.1]:       objectMode: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017297+00:00
> app[web.1]:       highWaterMark:
> 16384,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017297+00:00 app[web.1]:       finalCalled:
> false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017297+00:00 app[web.1]:       needDrain:
> false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017297+00:00 app[web.1]:       ending:
> false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017297+00:00 app[web.1]:       ended:
> false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017299+00:00 app[web.1]:       finished:
> false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017299+00:00 app[web.1]:       destroyed:
> false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017299+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> decodeStrings: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017299+00:00 app[web.1]:     
> defaultEncoding: 'utf8',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017300+00:00 app[web.1]:  
> length: 0,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017300+00:00 app[web.1]:       writing:
> false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017300+00:00 app[web.1]:       corked:
> 0,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017300+00:00 app[web.1]:       sync:
> false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017300+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> bufferProcessing: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017301+00:00 app[web.1]:  
> onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017301+00:00
> app[web.1]:       writecb: null,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017301+00:00
> app[web.1]:       writelen: 0,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017301+00:00
> app[web.1]:       afterWriteTickInfo:
> null,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017301+00:00 app[web.1]:       buffered:
> [],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017301+00:00 app[web.1]:       bufferedIndex:
> 0,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017301+00:00 app[web.1]:       allBuffers:
> true,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017302+00:00 app[web.1]:       allNoop:
> true,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017302+00:00 app[web.1]:       pendingcb:
> 0,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017302+00:00 app[web.1]:       constructed:
> true,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017302+00:00 app[web.1]:       prefinished:
> false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017302+00:00 app[web.1]:       errorEmitted:
> false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017302+00:00 app[web.1]:       emitClose:
> false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017302+00:00 app[web.1]:       autoDestroy:
> true,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017302+00:00 app[web.1]:       errored:
> null,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017303+00:00 app[web.1]:       closed:
> false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017303+00:00 app[web.1]:       closeEmitted:
> false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017303+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> [Symbol(kOnFinished)]: []2022-08-15T05:04:33.017303+00:00 app[web.1]: 
> },2022-08-15T05:04:33.017303+00:00 app[web.1]:     allowHalfOpen:
> false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017303+00:00 app[web.1]:     _sockname:
> null,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017303+00:00 app[web.1]:     _pendingData:
> null,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017304+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> _pendingEncoding: '',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017304+00:00 app[web.1]:     server: null,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017304+00:00 app[web.1]:     _server:
> null,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017304+00:00 app[web.1]:     parser:
> HTTPParser {2022-08-15T05:04:33.017304+00:00 app[web.1]:       '0':
> null,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017304+00:00 app[web.1]:       '1':
> [Function: parserOnHeaders],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017304+00:00
> app[web.1]:       '2': [Function:
> parserOnHeadersComplete],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017305+00:00 app[web.1]: 
> '3': [Function: parserOnBody],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017305+00:00
> app[web.1]:       '4': [Function:
> parserOnMessageComplete],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017305+00:00 app[web.1]: 
> '5': null,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017305+00:00 app[web.1]:       '6':
> null,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017305+00:00 app[web.1]:       _headers:
> [],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017306+00:00 app[web.1]:       _url:
> '',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017306+00:00 app[web.1]:       socket:
> [Circular *1],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017306+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> incoming: [Circular *2],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017306+00:00 app[web.1]:  
> outgoing: [ClientRequest],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017306+00:00 app[web.1]:
> maxHeaderPairs: 2000,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017306+00:00 app[web.1]:     
> _consumed: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017306+00:00 app[web.1]:       onIncoming: [Function:
> parserOnIncomingClient],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017306+00:00 app[web.1]:  
> [Symbol(resource_symbol)]:
> [HTTPClientAsyncResource]2022-08-15T05:04:33.017307+00:00 app[web.1]: 
> },2022-08-15T05:04:33.017307+00:00 app[web.1]:     _httpMessage:
> ClientRequest {2022-08-15T05:04:33.017307+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> _events: [Object: null prototype],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017307+00:00 app[web.1]:       _eventsCount: 2,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017307+00:00
> app[web.1]:       _maxListeners:
> undefined,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017307+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> outputData: [],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017307+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> outputSize: 0,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017308+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> writable: true,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017308+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> destroyed: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017308+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> _last: true,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017308+00:00 app[web.1]:       chunkedEncoding: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017308+00:00 app[web.1]:   
> shouldKeepAlive: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017308+00:00 app[web.1]:   
> maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017313+00:00
> app[web.1]:       _defaultKeepAlive:
> true,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017313+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017313+00:00
> app[web.1]:       sendDate: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017313+00:00
> app[web.1]:       _removedConnection:
> false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017313+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> _removedContLen: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017313+00:00 app[web.1]:       _removedTE: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017314+00:00 app[web.1]:       _contentLength: 0,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017314+00:00 app[web.1]:       _hasBody: true,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017314+00:00 app[web.1]:       _trailer: '',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017314+00:00 app[web.1]:       finished: true,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017314+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> _headerSent: true,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017314+00:00 app[web.1]:       _closed: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017314+00:00 app[web.1]:       socket: [Circular *1],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017315+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> _header: 'GET /api/search.php?from=LAX&to=SEA&depart=2022-08-24&sort=cost
> HTTP/1.1\r\n' +2022-08-15T05:04:33.017315+00:00 app[web.1]:        
> 'Host: skiplagged.com\r\n' +2022-08-15T05:04:33.017315+00:00
> app[web.1]:         'Connection: close\r\n'
> +2022-08-15T05:04:33.017315+00:00 app[web.1]:         '\r\n',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017316+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> _keepAliveTimeout: 0,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017316+00:00 app[web.1]:       _onPendingData: [Function: nop],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017316+00:00 app[web.1]:       agent: [Agent],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017316+00:00
> app[web.1]:       socketPath:
> undefined,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017316+00:00 app[web.1]:       method:
> 'GET',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017317+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> maxHeaderSize: undefined,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017317+00:00 app[web.1]: 
> insecureHTTPParser: undefined,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017317+00:00
> app[web.1]:       path:
> '/api/search.php?from=LAX&to=SEA&depart=2022-08-24&sort=cost',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017317+00:00
> app[web.1]:       _ended: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017318+00:00
> app[web.1]:       res: [Circular *2],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017318+00:00
> app[web.1]:       aborted: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017318+00:00
> app[web.1]:       timeoutCb: null,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017318+00:00
> app[web.1]:       upgradeOrConnect:
> false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017318+00:00 app[web.1]:       parser:
> [HTTPParser],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017319+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> maxHeadersCount: null,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017319+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> reusedSocket: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017319+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> host: 'skiplagged.com',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017319+00:00 app[web.1]:   
> protocol: 'http:',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017319+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017319+00:00 app[web.1]:
> [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017319+00:00
> app[web.1]:       [Symbol(corked)]: 0,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017320+00:00
> app[web.1]:       [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null
> prototype]2022-08-15T05:04:33.017320+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> },2022-08-15T05:04:33.017320+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 65,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017320+00:00
> app[web.1]:     [Symbol(kHandle)]: TCP
> {2022-08-15T05:04:33.017320+00:00 app[web.1]:       reading:
> true,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017320+00:00 app[web.1]:       onconnection:
> null,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017320+00:00 app[web.1]:      
> [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *1]2022-08-15T05:04:33.017321+00:00
> app[web.1]:     },2022-08-15T05:04:33.017321+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017321+00:00
> app[web.1]:     [Symbol(timeout)]:
> null,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017321+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017321+00:00 app[web.1]:  
> [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017321+00:00 app[web.1]:
> [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017321+00:00
> app[web.1]:     [Symbol(kCapture)]:
> false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017322+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017322+00:00
> app[web.1]:     [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]:
> false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017322+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]:
> 0,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017322+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017322+00:00 app[web.1]:  
> [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017322+00:00
> app[web.1]:     [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]:
> undefined2022-08-15T05:04:33.017323+00:00 app[web.1]:  
> },2022-08-15T05:04:33.017323+00:00 app[web.1]:   httpVersionMajor:
> 1,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017323+00:00 app[web.1]:   httpVersionMinor:
> 1,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017323+00:00 app[web.1]:   httpVersion:
> '1.1',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017323+00:00 app[web.1]:   complete:
> false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017323+00:00 app[web.1]:   rawHeaders:
> [2022-08-15T05:04:33.017323+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> 'Date',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017324+00:00 app[web.1]:     'Mon, 15 Aug
> 2022 05:04:33 GMT',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017324+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> 'Content-Type',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017324+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017324+00:00
> app[web.1]:     'Transfer-Encoding',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017324+00:00
> app[web.1]:     'chunked',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017324+00:00 app[web.1]:
> 'Connection',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017324+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> 'close',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017324+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> 'CF-Chl-Bypass',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017325+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> '1',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017325+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> 'Permissions-Policy',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017325+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> 'accelerometer=(),autoplay=(),camera=(),clipboard-read=(),clipboard-write=(),fullscreen=(),geolocation=(),gyroscope=(),hid=(),interest-cohort=(),magnetometer=(),microphone=(),payment=(),publickey-credentials-get=(),screen-wake-lock=(),serial=(),sync-xhr=(),usb=()',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017325+00:00
> app[web.1]:     'Cache-Control',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017326+00:00
> app[web.1]:     'private, max-age=0, no-store, no-cache,
> must-revalidate, post-check=0,
> pre-check=0',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017326+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> 'Expires',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017326+00:00 app[web.1]:     'Thu, 01
> Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017326+00:00 app[web.1]:   
> 'X-Frame-Options',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017326+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> 'SAMEORIGIN',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017326+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> 'Server',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017326+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> 'cloudflare',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017327+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> 'CF-RAY',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017327+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> '73af63de3ca4821e-IAD',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017327+00:00 app[web.1]:   
> 'alt-svc',2022-08-15T05:04:33.017327+00:00 app[web.1]:     'h3=":443";
> ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400'2022-08-15T05:04:33.017327+00:00
> app[web.1]:   ],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017327+00:00 app[web.1]:  
> rawTrailers: [],2022-08-15T05:04:33.017327+00:00 app[web.1]:  
> aborted: false,2022-08-15T05:04:33.017328+00:00 app[web.1]:   upgrade:
```

Comment: Have you tried any REST Client to verify the backend connection?

Comment: Can you explain to me what a REST Client is?